# Why am I getting warnings for overridable method call in the constructor, when nothing is being overriden?

Tags: java, netbeans

I’m getting the warning  “overridable method call in contractor” and I don’t know why. The class doesn’t `extend` or `implement` anything. When I click on the warning the suggestions are to
1. make the class final
2. make the method final
3. make the method static
4. make the method private

Why is this happening and what should I do? Here is the relevant code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Tester {

    public Tester(int minLength, int maxLength, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        rand = new Random();
        int[] randData = generateArray(minLength, maxLength, minValue, maxValue);//overridable method call in constructor
        procArr = new DataManager(randData);
        doTests();//overridable method call in constructor
    }

    public void doTests()
    {
        procArr.sort();
    }

    public int[] generateArray(int minLenght, int maxLength, int minVal, int maxVal)
    {
        final int length = getRandomVal(minLenght, maxLength);
        int arr[] = new int[length];
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            arr[i] = getRandomVal(minVal, maxVal);
        return arr;
    }


    private int getRandomVal(int min, int max)
    {
        int n = max - min + 1;
        int i = rand.nextInt(n);
        return min + i;
    }


    final private Random rand;
    final private DataManager procArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that warning because you call `doTests()` in your constructor. Since other people can extend your class and change the function, you have no guarantees that it will actually do what you expect it to. Having overridable methods in your constructor is a god way to have inconsistent/unexpected object states.

To remove the warning, make the method final, make it private, or make the class final.

Making the class final means that no other object can inherent from it. Making the method final means that no subclass can change the method's definition. Making the method private means that no other object can interact with it at all (so won't be able to change it).

If no other class needs that method, it's fine to make it private. Otherwise, the best way is probably to make the method final.

Comment: Ok. What are the difference in options of making the method final, make it private, or make the class final?

Comment: Either one works.  If the class is final, then no one can extend it and no one can override any methods at all.

Comment: @Celeritas Private means it can't be seen externally (and so is also effectively final). Final means it can be seen externally but can't be changed. Making the whole class final means nothing (about the class) can be changed because the class cannot be extended

Comment: @Celeritas updated my answer to explain the differences. Also, see Richard's comment.

Comment: Ok thanks. I noticed it doesn't matter where you place `final` in the methods signature, for example `public final void doTests()` or `final public void doTests()`. Is there a preferred way? When declaring final variables I like to put the final first as I want that to be the first thing people notice, though with method signatures I'm used for the access level being the first thing seen.

Comment: @Celeritas I've always seen it as `public final void doTests()`.

Comment: @Celeritas: see my edit for the preferred order for those modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's overridable.  Make it private or final.

```
private int[] generateArray(int minLenght, int maxLength, int minVal, int maxVal)
{
    final int length = getRandomVal(minLenght, maxLength);
    int arr[] = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        arr[i] = getRandomVal(minVal, maxVal);
    return arr;
}
```

The warning isn't complaining that you did override a method.  It's complaining that someone else could.  Which is bad for CTORs since then your CTOR will call a method that does god-knows-what.  Usually methods called from the CTOR are private.  Sometimes you want them public, so make them final too if they are public.

EDIT: Re. your question *"I noticed it doesn't matter where you place final in the methods signature, for example public final void doTests() or final public void doTests(). Is there a preferred way?"*

Yes there is.  The Java Language Specification [says the preferred order is:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3)

1. Annotations
2. public, protected, or private
3. abstract static final synchronized native strictfp

Comment: How is it overridable?

Comment: @Celeritas Annother class could extend this class and override that method.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you never want anyone to change your constructor at all. What you've done in your code is allow them to...

When someone subclasses your class and calls super(int, int, int, int) the doTests(); call is called on the subclass. So someone can change part of the base class' constructor's workings.